# Which web framework works well using Scala on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, scala, web-applications

I'm embarking on a project that will be hosted on Google App Engine, and having read several books on Scala, it's definitely the language I'd like to code in. The problem is which web framework to choose...

Lift seems like an obvious choice, but aside from the fact that I'm not warming to it's AJAX/Comet notations, it appears to be strongly biased in favor of a stateful server, which doesn't bode well with App Engine. I realize that stateless dispatchers are *possible* in Lift, but this appears to negate many of the features of the Lift framework.

Scala-GWT is not production ready, so isn't a good choice.

Mixing Java GWT in with Scala is possible, but negates all the advantages of Scala (i.e. we're right back to heaps of boilerplate code).

My *unqualified opinion* of Spiffy and Scalatra is that they're not particularly mature.

Hence the question:

Is there a *good* (i.e. reasonably mature) framework that can be used on Google App Engine (i.e. stateful client, stateless server) which plays nicely with scala?

Comment: Great question. Now that it's almost an year since the question was asked I would like to know what did you choose?

Comment: Scalatra explicitly says "Scalatra doesn't work on Google App Engine (GAE)." http://www.scalatra.org/2.2/guides/deployment/google-app-engine.html

Comment: +1. I want to do rest service in scala, also clients will be in gwt, ios and Android.

Answer (score 6):

Check out the [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.org).

I'm currently developing an application using Play! on GAE.

I found that it is fairly easy to get up and running. PLAY! + [the GAE module](http://www.playframework.org/modules/gae) + [the Siena module](http://www.playframework.org/modules/siena) is all you'll need.

Play! also has REST + JSON as first-class features. Using Play!, you'll also be more portable to other platforms if you find yourself banging your head against the GAE limitations.

Comment: Why does it work well with GAE? The link you provided doesn't give any info on this.

Comment: I tried using Play! for GAE and found the documentation very distributed between 1.x and 2.x, and tbh I couldn't get the GAE module working on 2.x at all.

Comment: I think this answer is outdated / misleading since it probably applies to Play 1. I have not heard of Play 2 being compatible with GAE.

Answer (score 1):

Scala + [Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org) could be fun, but I do not know about Wicket on GAE. Searching on Google seems to be positive.